# Nativescript app deploys, but doesn't appear on device

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm just starting to learn Nativescript, cause I want to develop an app version of a site I made. I went through their tutorial, and had no problems there. Then I created my own app using `tns create` and then added the Android platform using `tns platform add android`. Then I created a few pages, and tried to run it with `tns run android`, and it will successfully build and says it's deployed on the correct device (either Genymotion or my S6), but the app will not show up at all.

I tried creating another app with the basic template `tns create` makes, and running just that as is, and that won't show up either. The sampleGroceries tutorial app continues to show up though.

What could I be missing?

Comment: turn off the emulator and unplug the usb then run `adb kill-server` then turn on the emulator again and run `tns run android`

Comment: Can you able to see that app in your mobile(S6) or in your Emulator ?

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I can see the sampleGroceries app from the tutorial in the emulator and on my S6. I can't see my app on either.

Comment: @DanielEngle : Then I think, that app has successfully pushed to your device/emulator due to some reason. Check in your console at the time of building your app. Maybe somewhere some error might've generating